# Play Framework 1.2.x Pdf module issue while generationg pdf in Job/Offline

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to generate the PDF in a Job instead of creating it in controller as it is going to take time. I am using the PDF generation code shown below. This is the standard function that Play framework provides.

```
PDF.writePDF(file,"test.html",data, options);
```

Now when I run this I get Null pointer exception. I debugged the issue in the Play framework PDF modules source code. Below is the line where the null pointer is coming because it is trying to access the request object, but as I have called the code from a Job not from Controller the request is null.

```
 public static void writePDF(OutputStream out, Object... args) {
    final Http.Request request = Http.Request.current();
    final String format = request.format;
```

Is there any other way of achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the [Request](https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Http.java) class shows that the current variable is public and that it is stored in a ThreadLocal. You should then be able to set a own Request object at the beginning of the job. Use the following code to create a own Request object.

```
Http.Request request = Http.Request.createRequest(...);
Http.Request.current.set(request);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked. Just to add, with this I need to set the response, flash and param implicit objects.

Comment: Hi Paul, running into the same problem, could you show an example of "with this I need to set the response, flash and param implicit objects."